# Gaming Map Engine, Final Fantasy Tactics Esk

Tags: javascript, game-engine

I was searching the internet trying to figure out if it would be possible to build a final fantasy tactics style World Map Engine in JavaScript.  The map and point locations are simple, I am still left to wonder how you could make a path between the points that isn't necessarily straight and a sprite would walk along that path.

FFT map
http://www.vintagevideogamer.net/wp-content/uploads/2012/04/world_map.jpg

Does anyone know what that style of maping is called?  (Wikipedia didn't have a term)

Or are there any existing examples of such a program?

I am looking at either using Canvas or just Native JS to attempt it.

Comment: Most path finding (in games) uses A* or some derivative thereof. But that has nothing to do with `Canvas`, so I'm not sure if it's what you're looking for.

Comment: I've made Astar path finding things before, its nothing like it.  It walks a non-block like or linear path.  I will find a youtube video.  Thank you for trying though.  It has to do with Canvas because a sprite walks along the path on the map.  The paths are show on the image above.

Comment: A* finds a path in a network of nodes with weighted edges (somebody correct me if I got the terminology wrong). If you weigh your connections by their length, it should be able to find the best path. Any idea why yours didn't work?

Comment: Again, its not Linear, I do not want the best path.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen: He's not trying to do path-finding. He's making an explicit path and trying to get a sprite to trace along said path. He wants to know how to encode such a path and interact with it.

Comment: To a small extent Frank is correct, because it needs to find the shortest path from Dot 1 to dot 24, however the more complex issue is walking from dot 1 to dot 2 in a non-linear path.  Ultimately I want to build an engine to allow you to "draw" a line and the system then understands it follows this path to get from A to B before worrying about A -> B -> C -> ...Z in a pathfinding.

Comment: @Iscariot: Yes, absolutely you'll require a pathfinding algorithm to find the shortest path on the map, but that's not what the question is about. Frank misread your question and intent; I was trying to clarify for him that the pathfinding piece was not your problem.

Comment: I have just seen a lot of games over of the years have used it and I am surprised that such a small amount of information is available when searching for it.

Comment: @Iscariot: Also, the A* algorithm assigns a "weight" to each path it attempts and then finds the path with the smallest cumulative weight. In my example below, your "weight" would be the duration. As such, you'd still be finding the best path (series of roads to take with the lowest duration/weight), despite each path being a curved line.

Answer (score 0):

You could encode such a path as a series of line segments with relative coordinates. Suppose you wanted a path like such:

```
|
\ _
```

Where each line is 10 pixels. You could encode that as a javascript array of line-segments (with duration to indicate the number of seconds or milliseconds it should take to traverse that segment):

```
[
    {"start_x":0,"start_y":0,"stop_x":0,"stop_y":10,"duration":2},
    {"start_x":0,"start_y":10,"stop_x":10,"stop_y":20,"duration":3},
    {"start_x":10,"start_y":20,"stop_x":20,"stop_y":20,"duration":2}
]
```

Then you just use time estimates to find the intermediate points between the start of a segment and the end of a segment. The current offset would be:

```
var pct_complete = elapsed_time / line_segment.duration,
    x_diff = (line_segment.stop_x - line_segment.start_x),
    y_diff = (line_segment.stop_y - line_segment.start_y),
    render_x = line_segment.start_x + (x_diff * pct_complete),
    render_y = line_segment.start_y + (y_diff * pct_complete);
```

Where elapsed_time is the time since you started the segment. As I mentioned, use relative coordinates and then you just have to adjust render_x/y for the path's position in the world and the screen offset.

For smoother turns use smaller line segments.

Comment: I understand.  I was more just hoping someone knew the name of that style of movement.  I am probably going to use Cal and Geometry in order to draw paths.  I have to come up with a creative way to have them dynamically created in a JS engine.  IE, I build the engine that makes this and people can use the tool to create maps for the end user.

Comment: I believe "Fixed Path Map" or "Road Map" are your best bets in terms of what to call it, but there's not much info out there for either term. Either way, you asked for an example, and mine's crude but workable.

Comment: http://raphaeljs.com  I found that, it looks like a start, their curve demo and bounce demo looking promising.

Comment: Those are using mathematical models to create curved paths, which is certainly an option, but you might have a hard time getting it to do exactly what you want. Good luck.